# Errors need guidance

Tags: c++, error-handling

Need help, please guide me on this. 
How to solve the errors as stated below?

> - 30:24:error:expected ')' before ',' token
> - In member function 'int Address::compareTo(const Address&)':
> - 41:26:error:'std::string' has no member named 'compareTo'

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Address {
      int    houseNumber;
      string street;
      int    apartmentNumber;
      string city;
      string state;
      string zipCode; // e.g., "47405-1234"
      Address(int houseNumber, 
              string street, 
              // no apartmentNumber  
              string city, 
              string state, 
              string zipCode) { 
        this->houseNumber = houseNumber; 
        this->street = street; 
        this->city = city; 
        this->state = state; 
        this->zipCode = zipCode; 
      } 
      Address(int houseNumber, 
              string street, 
              int apartmentNumber, 
              string city, 
              string state, 
              string zipCode) { 
        this(houseNumber, street, city, state, zipCode);
        this->apartmentNumber = apartmentNumber; 
      } 
      void print(void) {
             std::cout << "Street: " << street << "\nCity: " 
                 << city << "\nState: " << state << "\nPostal Code: " << zipCode;
    }

      int compareTo(const Address &a) { 
        // same conventions as for Strings
        return this->zipCode.compareTo(a); 
      }
    };
```

Comment: "41:26:error:'std::string' has no member named 'compareTo'"? See [std::string reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ a few errors here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276247/c-a-few-errors-here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/), not `compareTo` (Java, C# anyone)?

Also, note that `angle` is not declared in your scope. Did you mean:

```
return this->zipCode.compare("angel");
```

or did you just omit the variable?

You also ("should" where applicable):

- don't need `this->`
- as an alternative to `compare` you can use `==` (this returns `true` for equality)
- `print` and `compareTo` should be marked as `const`
- use member initializer lists in the constructors
- remove the `using namespace std;` from the header
- separate the implementations in source files
- use include guards for headers
- proper indentation
- pass `string` parameters to the constructor by `const &`...

Answer (score 1):

> 30:24:error:expected ')' before ',' token

You have

```
this(houseNumber, street, city, state, zipCode);
```

which is nonsense; `this` is a pointer to the object being constructed, not a function.

Presumably, you're trying to call the other constructor to initialise some of the data members. In C++11, you can delegate to another constructor, although I don't know whether any compilers support that yet. This must be done in the initialiser list, not the constructor body:

```
Address(/*args*/) : Address(/*other args*/), apartmentNumber(apartmentNumber) {}
```

If that doesn't work, then you will have to either duplicate the initialisations in both constructors, or move them into a member function and call that from both constructors.

You might also consider leaving out the constructors and using aggregate initialisation instead:

```
Address address = {
    123, "Fake Street", /* and so on */
};
```

although you should only do this for classes that simply hold data with no class invariants to establish.

> 41:26:error:'std::string' has no member named 'compareTo'

As the error says, there is no `compareTo` member in `std::string`. However, there is a member called `compare`. Assuming that your comment implies that you want the same behaviour as Java's `String.compareTo`, then that is what you want.

However, in C++ it's much more common to make objects comparable by overriding comparison operators (`==`, `<`, etc.); doing that will make it more convenient to use with standard algorithms, and other code that uses similar idioms. You might want to think about doing that sort of thing rather than trying to use idioms from other languages.